# hierarchical cluster labeling with plots

Tags: r, plot, label, cluster-analysis, hierarchical

I have a distance matrix for ~20 elements, which I am using to do hierarchical clustering in R.  Is there a way to label elements with a plot or a picture instead of just numbers, characters, etc?

So, instead of the leaf nodes having numbers, it'd have small plots or pictures.

Here is why I'm interested in this functionality.  I have 2-D scatterplots like these (color indicates density)

http://www.pnas.org/content/108/51/20455/F2.large.jpg   (Note that this is not my own data)

I have to analyze hundreds of such 2-D scatter plots, and am trying out various distance metrics which I'm feeding on to hclust.  The idea is to quickly (albeit roughly) cluster the 2-D plots to figure out the larger patterns, so we can minimize the number of time-consuming, follow-up experiments.  Hence, it'll be ideal to label the dendrogram leaves with the appropriate 2-D plots.

Comment: what have you tried? can you add a reproducible example. this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @flodel if you read the question, I want to label leaves with plots.  Instead of using strings or colors, I want to have small pictures, since I am clustering 2-D scatterplots by pattern.

Comment: @agstudy thanks, unfortunately, I haven't seen this in R before, that's why I'm asking.  Basically, I have data that looks like this (this is not my data, btw): http://www.pnas.org/content/108/51/20455/F2.large.jpg  colors indicate density ...except I have hundreds of these, and I'm trying to cluster these so I can quickly assess the different classes of behaviors....and it would be extremely helpful to have a dendrogram labeled with the appropriate plots

Comment: maybye this can help you as a first try http://gastonsanchez.wordpress.com/2012/10/03/7-ways-to-plot-dendrograms-in-r/

Answer (score 4):

There is one option :

1. Convert your hclust using **as.dendrogram**
2. use **dendrapply** to apply a function through the tree. The function customize the leaf.

here one example , where I color my cluster and I change the chape of the node.

```
hc = hclust(dist(mtcars[1:10,]))
hcd <- as.dendrogram(hc)
mycols <- grDevices::rainbow(attr(hcd,"members"))
i <- 0 
colLab <- function(n) {
    if(is.leaf(n)) {
      i <<- i + 1
      a <- attributes(n)
      attr(n, "nodePar") <-
        c(a$nodePar, list(lab.col = mycols[i],lab.bg='grey50',pch=sample(19:25,1)))
      attr(n, "frame.plot") <- TRUE
    }
    n
  }
clusDendro = dendrapply(hcd, colLab)
# make plot
plot(clusDendro, main = "Customized Dendrogram", type = "triangle")
```

[image]

## Idea:

If you try to customize the node label to an map it to an url link. So when you click on the leaf name , you navigate to its image. I think it is not hard to do.